# Odata orderby x-y

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible with Odata but, thought I'd ask if anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this before I go off and write a service operation.

Basically, I want to add an $orderby onto the end of an odata qry, a bit like this:

$orderby=SomeIntField-SomeOtherIntField

easy to do in SQL, not sure on how to do this with OData and WCF data services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit - although I initially thought you couldn't do this, it turns out you can. See section [2.2.3.6.1.1 Common Expression Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541448%28PROT.10%29.aspx) of the MS-ODATA specification for syntax examples. You would need `$orderby=SomeIntField sub SomeOtherIntField`.

Comment: I would just like to add that lot of services might not support arbitrary expressions in orderby. So if you're targeting a single service where it works, great. But if you're targeting unknown services, I would be wary about relying on this.